# A problem on tangent and secant lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

My question is the following:

*Assume a point $A$ outside some circle, and a point $X$ on the same circle, such that $AX$ is ***not*** a diameter of the circle. Draw $Y$ as the point of intersection between the circle and the (extesion of the) line $AX$. Draw the tangents to the circle in points $X$ and $Y$, and denote their point of intersection with $Z$. Also draw the two tangents $AB$, $AC$ to the circle, where $B$, $C$ are points on the circle. Prove that $Z$ lies on the extension of the line $BC$.*

[image]

The approaches I have tried until now involved either

- analyzing triangle similarities and searching for equal angles (many pairs of angles subtend the same arcs),
- calculating cross ratios (considering the drawing as a two-point
  perspective drawing of a circle),
- establishing a particular origin of linear coordinates and searching vector expressions for the positions of all points,
- writing all points in polar coordinates,

although without any significant progress. Can you please help me formally solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! A small tip for the future: most tags have a tag description which will tell you what sort of posts they should be put on. In particular, the algebraic-geometry tag explains that "[t]his tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry."

Comment: See [harmonic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_quadrilateral).

Comment: For more properties and detailed proofs, see [this](https://fs.unm.edu/ScArt/SomePpropertiesOfTheHarmonic.pdf).

Comment: See this very close recent [question] (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4864657/305862)

Answer (score 2):

We're going to use two results on the polar(*) of a point with respect to a circle.

(1) if $P$ is exterior to a circle $\mathcal C, $ then the polar of $P$ is $(TT')$, where $T$ and $T'$ are the "tangent points";

(2)  if $P$ and $M $ are two points different of the center of $\mathcal C$ , then $M$ belongs to the polar of $P$ iff $P$  belongs to the polar of $M$.

According to (1),

> $\color{green}{BC}$ is the polar of $\color{blue}{A}$ and $\color{grey}{XY}$ the polar of $\color{red}{Z}$.

According to (2),

> as $\color{blue}{A}$ is on $\color{grey}{XY}, \color{red}{Z}$ is on $\color{green}{BC}$. $\square $

---

(*) To define the polar of a point $P$ in a circle $\mathcal C$ with center $O$ and radius $R$, you first determine $P' \in OP$ s.t.$$\overline{OP}.\overline{OP'}=R^2$$ then the polar is the perpendicular to $OP$ passing through $P'$.

---

Let's Prove Quickly (1):
[image]

Let $P$ be a point outside the circle, $T$ the tangent point, and $H$ the foot of the perpendicular to $OP$ passing through $T$.

$OTP$ and $OTH$ are similar. So $\frac{OT}{OH}=\frac{OP}{OT}$. So $OP.OH=OT^2=R^2$. So $P'=H$ and $T$ belongs to the polar $p$ of $P$.$\square$

---

Let's Prove Quickly (2):
[image]
With the notations in the figure, it is assumed that$$P\in m$$with $m$, polar of $M$
Let $MH$ be perpendicular to $OP$.
$OMH$ and $OM'P$ are similar. So $\frac{OH}{OM'}=\frac{OM}{OP}$. So $OP.OH=OM.OM'=R^2$. So $P'=H$ and $$M\in p$$where $p$ is the polar of $P$.$\square$

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you happen to know where could I find rigorous proofs of these mentioned results (especially the double implication in [2])? The concept of polars and poles is new to me and I want to understand these properties better. Also, do you happen to know what criteria could substitute the "why?" in the other answer regarding harmonic quadrilaterals? How can we riguously prove the statement "for fixed points B,X,Y there is only one point C on the circle such that BXCY is harmonic"?

Comment: See this very recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4864657/305862)

Comment: @Qwerty Boy : You can find the proofs of (1) and (2) in GEOMETRY REVISITED by Coxeter, in paragraph 6.1 (it's very quick and efficient: definition of the polar then two similar triangles and presto;
 It would almost be possible to do it in my answer.)

Comment: Hmm, I haven't studied Coexter, but your Polar is just a perpendicular passing through the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) of $P$. And the second idea is just an implication of the fact that inversion is an involution. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Building off of D S's comments (and the wikipedia article on harmonic quadrilaterals), we can see that $BXCY$ is harmonic.

However, if we let $C'$ be the other (one being $B$) intersection of ray $ZB$ and the circle, then $ZBC'$ is a line and $BXC'Y$ is harmonic. Since for fixed points $B,X,Y$ there is only one point $C$ on the circle such that $BXCY$ is harmonic (why?), meaning we must have $C=C'$ and thus $Z,B,C$ are collinear.

Comment: More directly, the construction implies $BCXY$ harmonic, which implies $Z,B,C$ collinear.

Comment: 852619 and @DS , thanks for answering. How can we riguously prove the statement "for fixed points B,X,Y there is only one point C on the circle such that BXCY is harmonic"? Why are we allowed to do this assumption?

Comment: If you look at the second picture on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_quadrilateral), the angle is uniquely determined, so the point is also uniquely determined.

Comment: @QwertyBoy did you see my second link? Also, Evan Chen's EGMO has a nice exposition.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I should prove the properties (useful here) of the Harmonic quadrilateral stated in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_quadrilateral).

---

We define a harmonic quadrilateral as a cyclic quadrilateral which has the product of opposite sides equal.

> **Lemma 1**: Given three points $A,B,C$, and tangents $BT,CT$ to the circumcircle $(ABC)$, and $D = (ABC) \cap AT$, the quadrilateral $ABDC$ is harmonic.

**Proof**: By sine rule in $\Delta ABT$ and $\Delta ACT$,
$$\frac{AB}{BT} = \frac{\sin(\angle ATB)}{\sin(\angle BAT)} = \frac{\sin(\angle DTB)}{\sin(\angle BAD)} \tag{1}$$
$$\frac{AC}{CT} = \frac{\sin(\angle ATC)}{\sin(\angle CAT)} = \frac{\sin(\angle DTC)}{\sin(\angle CAD)} \tag{2}$$
By sine rule in $\Delta DTB$ and $\Delta DCT$,
$$\frac{DB}{TD} = \frac{\sin(\angle DTB)}{\sin(\angle TBD)} = \frac{\sin(\angle DTB)}{\sin(\angle BAD)} \tag{3}$$
$$\frac{DC}{TD} = \frac{\sin(\angle DTC)}{\sin(\angle TCD)} = \frac{\sin(\angle DTC)}{\sin(\angle CAD)} \tag{4}$$
Multiplying (1) and (4) and comparing with product of (2) and (3), we have
$$\frac{AB\cdot DC}{BT\cdot TD} = \frac{\sin(\angle DTB) \sin(\angle DTC)}{\sin(\angle BAD)\sin(\angle CAD)} = \frac{AC \cdot DB}{CT \cdot TD}$$
Since $BT = CT$, we have $AB\cdot DC = AC \cdot DB$ as desired.

> **Lemma 2**: In a harmonic quadrilateral $ABDC$, the tangents from $B$ and $C$ concur on $AD$ (this is just the converse of Lemma 1).

**Proof**: Let the two tangents be $BT$ and $CT$. Join $AT$ and let $AT \cap (ABDC) = D'$. This implies that $ABD'C$ is also harmonic, so that
$$\frac{DB}{DC} = \frac{AB}{AC} = \frac{D'B}{D'C}$$
implying
$$\frac{\sin(\angle DCB)}{\sin(\angle DBC)} = \frac{\sin(\angle D'CB)}{\sin(\angle D'BC)}$$This means that $D=D'$ since the function
$f(X) = \frac{\sin(\angle XCB)}{\sin(\angle XBC)}$ on fixed arc $BC$ of a fixed circle is monotonic.

Instead of analyzing $f$, one could also provide a more elementary, albeit lengthy, proof using the fact that $\angle BDC = \angle BD'C$, and arguing that if $\sin(\angle DCB) < \sin(\angle D'CB) \iff \angle DCB < \angle D'CB$ also implies $\sin(\angle DBC)<\sin(\angle D'BC) \iff \angle DBC<\angle D'BC$. However, care must be taken to handle acute-obtuse configurations here.

---

In your figure, lemma 1 implies $BXCY$ is harmonic, lemma 2 implies $Z$ lies on $BC$.